# ‘The great storm in/of 1987’

Tags: prepositions, definite-article, indefinite-article

> My father lost his life during the great storm of 1987.

I’m not familiar with the structure ‘the ... of (time)’. I would say **a great storm in 1987**. Does **the great storm of 1987** refer to a particular storm that everybody knows or is it similar to **a great storm in 1987**? Can I say **the great storm in 1987**? What is the difference?

Comment: It probably refers to the storm that many people in the UK know about - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Storm_of_1987

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say, "The Great Storm of 1987", that implies that there is one particular storm that happened that year that was particularly notable. I wouldn't necessarily expect everyone in the world to know what storm you're talking about, but almost everyone who lives in the area affected by it would know. At that point "the Great Storm of 1987" is like a proper noun, it's the name of the thing.

If you are referring to a more mundane storm, not one huge storm that people will remember for decades but simply some big storm, you would say "a big storm in 1987". You don't say "the", you say "a", and you don't say "of", you say "in".

For example, I used to live in a town called Xenia (Ohio) that was hit by several tornadoes over the years, but one in particular in 1974 did a huge amount of damage. People in town regularly referred to it as "the Tornado of 1974", and surrounding areas referred to it as "the Xenia Tornado of 1974". We had another one in 2000 that was also pretty destructive, though not as bad as the 1974 tornado, so that was "the Tornado of 2000".

Ooh, I'm suddenly reminded of a smaller one that happened in the middle. After the tornado I looked over my property for damage and saw that it had torn out a tree and carried the lid off my garbage can while leaving the garbage can itself behind. I was pretty annoyed about the garbage can lid. Then I learned that it had taken the roof of my neighbor's house. He was strangely unsympathetic to my whining about my garbage can.

Comment: If I don’t refer to any particular storm, can I say ‘a great storm’ instead of ‘a big storm’? Btw, I don’t mean anything but the story about the middle tornado and the neighbor sounds funny to me.

Comment: Sure, "a big storm", "a great storm", "a very heavy rain", there are many words you can use. But note that when referring to a specific well-known event, they often have a "standard name". Like, "The Great Stock Market Crash of 1929". Grammatically, it would be correct to describe it as "the market collapse" or many other terms, but it's commonly referred to as "The Great Stock Market Crash", so if you call it something else, people might not realize you're talking about the same event.

Answer (score 1):

It refers to a particular great storm that the speaker expects his listener to know about. If it were just any storm, then "a big storm in 1987" would fit. The word "great" isn't usually used to refer to just any storm. (Consider, for example, the "Great Flood of 1993" in the midwestern U.S.)
Now, there are more than a few events that merit the term "great", so the reference is made specific by "of 1987".
Note, however, that there is nothing inherent in the meanings of "in" and "of" that determines the usage, but that is how the words are used.